# React setState not updating reduced array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a pretty simple custom component: two `select` lists with buttons to move the `options` from the **available** (left) list to the **selected** (right) list. Naturally, the moved element should no longer show up on the list it was moved from. Though both buttons successfully add the element to the target, it doesn't remove from the source, because when I pass the reduced array of items to `setState`, the render still returns with the original list.

**EDIT** posting most of the component code for clarification. The problem methods are the `addItems` and `removeItems`, where `setState` is called. In both cases, whichever array property is being reduced/filtered is the one not updating; the one being added to always updates properly.

```
    ... imports
    interface JoinedListState {
        availableItems: ListItem[]
        selectedItems: ListItem[]
    }

    export class JoinedList extends React.Component<JoinedListState, any>{
    // Create new arrays of the proper available and selected then set the new 
    // state
        private addItems(newItems: ListItem[]) {
            let oldSelected =  this.props.selectedItems;
            oldSelected.push.apply(oldSelected, newItems);
            let newSelected = oldSelected.sort((a, b) => {
                let nameA = a.value.toUpperCase();
                let nameB = b.value.toUpperCase();
                if (nameA < nameB) {
                    return -1
                }
                return 1
            });
            let newAvailable = this.props.availableItems
                .slice(0) // updated on recommendation of Sasha Kos
                .filter((item) => {
                    return newItems.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id) == -1
                });
            this.setState({
                availableItems: newAvailable,
                selectedItems: newSelected
            });
        }
        // Create new arrays of the proper available and selected then set the 
        //new state
        private removeItems(removedItems: ListItem[]) {
             .. same approach as addItems
            let newSelected = this.props.selectedItems.filter((item) => {
            // return only the items whose id does not exist on the newly 
            //removed items list
                return removedItems.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id) == -1
            })
            this.setState({
                availableItems: newAvailable,
                selectedItems: newSelected
            })
        }

        // Get the selected items by querying the DOM and send them to function 
        // to update state
         addSelected(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
                // Code removed for brevity:  uses the event object to find the 
                //selected objects and builds a ListItem array called 'selected' 
                //to pass to addItems
                this.addItems(selected)
            }  

            removeSelected(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
                // Code removed for brevity:  uses the event object to find the 
                //selected objects and builds a ListItem array called 'selected' 
                //to pass to addItems
                this.removeItems(selected)
            }

        render() {
            let aItems = this.renderOptionList(this.props.availableItems),
                sItems = this.renderOptionList(this.props.selectedItems);
            return (
                <div className='joined-list-container'>
                    <select key='available_list' className='available-list form- 
   control' multiple>
                        {aItems}
                    </select>
                    <span className='button-container'>
                        <button key='button1' className='btn btn-success' 
    onClick={this.addSelected.bind(this)}>
                            <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'> 
   </span>
                        </button>
                        <button key='button2' className='btn btn-danger' 
    onClick={this.removeSelected.bind(this)}>
                            <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'> 
   </span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <select key='selected_list' className='selected-list form- 
   control' multiple>
                        {sItems}
                    </select>
               </div>
            )
        }

        renderOptionList(items: ListItem[]) {
            return items.map((item, idx) => {
                let key = `${item.value}_${idx}`
                return (
                    <option value={item.id} key={key}>{item.value}</option>
                )
            })
        }
     }
```

(Sorry for any flawed formatting, posting was tricky)

When this kicks off the new render, the selectedItems list is properly updated with the new item(s), but the availableItems is always the original array (yes I've ensured that the `newAvailable` array is properly filtered down), and even when I try

```
    this.setState({
        availableItems: [],
        selectedItems: newSelected
    })
```

I get the original availableItems array on the next render.

Is there some nuance to returning similar-but-shorter arrays to state via `setState`? I can't find anything referencing this behavior, and not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you initializing your state? I see 'let aItems = this.renderOptionList(this.props.availableItems)' but if this.props.availableItems never changes, renderOptionsList will always return the same thing. I am not certain this is the problem, though, because then why would selectedItems work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
let oldSelected =  this.props.selectedItems;
        oldSelected.push.apply(oldSelected, newItems);
```

You are updating this.props.selectedItems here, but for availableItems:

```
let newAvailable = this.props.availableItems
            .slice(0) // updated on recommendation of Sasha Kos
            .filter((item) => {
                return newItems.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id) == -1
            });
```

Here, you do not directly update this.props.availableItems. The reason this matters is that when you call setState and render is triggered these methods:

```
let aItems = this.renderOptionList(this.props.availableItems),
            sItems = this.renderOptionList(this.props.selectedItems);
```

are using this.props to return arrays, NOT this.state. this.props.selectedItems has changed, and thus returns a different array, while this.props.availableItems has not changed.

tl;dr - use this.state instead of this.props when passing the arrays to your renderOptionList method.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need the .slice.

Comment: Great! This worked. This was my first attempt at a "pure" React component (had been using Redux up to this point) but I see where I went astray here; obviously setState wouldn't update this.props, so unless I explicitly change it, props won't change.

Comment: @brocoli_rob I agree with Devin. Btw i think you can improve your code. I made this jsfiddle maybe can help http://jsfiddle.net/8jc6zbw9/2/ It's clean JS not React.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that is a lot cleaner. Only issue was the use of map resulted in a new array with an all uppercase value; I just use uppercase to check ordering but want the text to preserve the case as it appeared. This worked perfectly for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/sn1vkupm/
Thanks again guys

Answer (score 1):

According to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Array.prototype.filter should create new array, but described symptoms says that you just get 2 references to one array so there is no rerender. So please try this

```
let newAvailable = this.props.availableItems
  .slice(0) /* clones your array */
  .filter((item) => {
    return newItems.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id) == -1
  });

this.setState({
    availableItems: newAvailable,
    selectedItems: newSelected
});
```

[image: Edit r40q9x3vxn]

Comment: Tried, still failed. newAvailable was the correctly-filtered array I expected, but when the component's render method was called, it was still the original array.

Again, even passing an empty array does not have the desired effect, so it's something regarding the way React handles property merging that I'm not understanding.

Comment: It's 126 lines but I'll try to post a summarized version that hits all the key points.

Comment: Here is a very good tool for code exchange `https://codesandbox.io/s/new`